# Issue on BillingClient.queryProductDetailsAsyn when call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged, android-billing

When I do *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()* into
**onProductDetailsResponse** it seems that the callback stays pending and the Recycleview doesn't show anything

I'm upgrading the Google Play Billing Library on my app, form 3 highter, I've the same issue on 4.1 and 5.

I retrieve my Subscriptions as Google require:

Define my productId

```
List<String> skuList = Application.getSubscritionsSkuList();
for (String sku : skuList) {
List<Product> productList.add(Product.newBuilder()
.setProductId(sku)
.setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
.build());
```

Define my RecycleView and set My adapter

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.SubscritionsList);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
SubscriptionAdapter subscriptionAdapter = new SubscriptionAdapter(
        context.getApplicationContext(), getActivity(), inventoryAsyncSub);
recyclerView.setAdapter(subscriptionAdapter);
```

Then retrieve the Subscriptions form the Store

```
QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(productList)
        .build();

billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
        params,
        new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
            public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                inventoryAsyncSub.addAll(productDetailsList);
                subscriptionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
);
```

The issue is: when I do **subscriptionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** it seems that the callback from **queryProductDetailsAsync** stays pending and the Recycleview doesn't show anything till I scroll it and navigating out from this Fragment the app stays waiting something: no other callback works

First I thought that it depend form deprecated method **querySkuDetailsAsync()** so following the [Google guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5#showing-products) I migrated to **queryProductDetailsAsync** method, but the issue still persist.

My Adapter has got any of characteristic:

```
public class SubscriptionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubscriptionAdapter.Viewholder>{

    public Object setOnItemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<ProductDetails> InventoryAsyncSub;
    private static ClickListener clickListener;

    public SubscriptionAdapter(
            Context context,
            Activity activity,
            List<ProductDetails> InventoryAsyncSub
    ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.InventoryAsyncSub = InventoryAsyncSub;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SubscriptionAdapter.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subscrition_card, parent, false);
        return new Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubscriptionAdapter.Viewholder holder, int position) {
         ProductDetails subScr = InventoryAsyncSub.get( position );

        PurchaseHandlerTools.setItemTitle( activity, holder.name, subScr.getTitle() );
        holder.description.setText( subScr.getDescription() );
        holder.pricesBox.findViewById( R.id.item_price);
        TextView price = holder.pricesBox.findViewById( R.id.item_price);
        price.setText( subScr.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getPricingPhases().getPricingPhaseList().get(0).getFormattedPrice() );
        
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return InventoryAsyncSub.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView name;
        private TextView description;
        private LinearLayout pricesBox;

        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.submition_name);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.submition_description);
            pricesBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.purchase_btn);
            itemView.setOnClickListener( this::onClick );
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onItemClick( getAdapterPosition(), v );
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        SubscriptionAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener{
        void onItemClick( int position, View view );

    }

}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you able to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and it is quite annoying since the docs don't tell you about it but the `onProductDetailsResponse` is somehow blocking the UI thread. I couldn't even show a simply dialog in this listener.

Therefore you have to put every UI modification to the UI thread like this and it works like a charm for me:

```
  public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {

         new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                     //UI modification goes here
    
                    }
                });

            }
```